# How to express m in terms of a?

Tags: quadratics

I have to solve this question:

The quadratic function f(x) = 2x² + ax - 1 in x satisfies
f(-1)≥-3
,f(2)≥3

Let us consider the minimum value m of f(x)

(1) m can be expressed in terms of a as:
m = -A/B a² - C

(2) The range of the values of a such that f(x) satisfies condition 1 is -2≤a≤4

Where A, B and C are just the blanks to fill the answers, but what i don't understand is how to express m in terms of a

Comment: Hint: *f(x)* is a upward-opening parabola with the $y$-value of its vertex being $m$ (it's probably a good idea to think through why this is the case).

Comment: I see, it was very simple, i poorly interpreted the statement, i thought m was a variable with a minimum value  in f(x), thank you very much!